# How to make checkbox checked in jQuery onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

Here I am doing edit form. I have two arrays. In one array (`allAmenities`) I am having all amenities names; second array (`particularPropertyAmenity`) has only two amenity names.

I want to make this amenity names checkbox checked. How can I do this?

```js
var htmlString = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allAmenities = {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
        "amenityId": "1",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Lift",

      }, {

        "amenityId": "2",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Gym",
      }, {

        "amenityId": "3",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
      }, {

        "amenityId": "4",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Power backup",
      }, {

        "amenityId": "5",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Security",
      },

    ]
  };



  var particularPropertyAmenity = [{
    "amenityName": "Lift",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }, {
    "amenityName": "Security",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }]

  htmlString += '<form>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br></br><span id="linz"></span>';

  $.each(allAmenities['data'], function(key, value) {

    htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="' + value.amenityName + '"> ' + value.amenityName + '';
  });
  $('#linz').append(htmlString);

  htmlString += '</form>';

  $('.rentEdit').empty().append(htmlString);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentEdit"></div>
```

#### Expected Output:

Lift & Security checkbox has to be checked.

Comment: Added checked i.e. `'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" checked name=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current amenities exists in Array using `Array.some()` and add `checked` attribute based on *truthy*

```
var setChecked = particularPropertyAmenity.some(function(e) {
  return e.amenityName == value.amenityName;
});
htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" ' + (setChecked ? 'checked' : '') + ' name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="' + value.amenityName + '"> ' + value.amenityName + '<br>';
```

```js
var htmlString = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allAmenities = {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
        "amenityId": "1",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Lift",

      },
      {

        "amenityId": "2",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Gym",
      },
      {

        "amenityId": "3",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
      },
      {

        "amenityId": "4",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Power backup",
      },
      {

        "amenityId": "5",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Security",
      },

    ]
  };



  var particularPropertyAmenity = [{
      "amenityName": "Lift",
      "amenityStatus": "Active"
    },
    {
      "amenityName": "Security",
      "amenityStatus": "Active"
    }
  ]

  htmlString += '<form>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br></br><span id="linz"></span>';

  $.each(allAmenities['data'], function(key, value) {

    var setChecked = particularPropertyAmenity.some(function(e) {
      return e.amenityName == value.amenityName;
    });
    htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" ' + (setChecked ? 'checked' : '') + ' name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="' + value.amenityName + '"> ' + value.amenityName + '<br>';
  });
  $('#linz').append(htmlString);

  htmlString += '</form>';

  $('.rentEdit').empty().append(htmlString);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentEdit"></div>
```

Comment: Think like both array values has to come dynamic.that how it will work this code

Comment: @RohitM both values are validated using `particularPropertyAmenity` array.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector:

```
  $.each( particularPropertyAmenity, function( key, value ) {  
                   if(value.amenityStatus=="Active")
                   {
                    $("input[value='"+value.amenityName+"']").prop("checked",true);
                   }
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var htmlString = '';
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var allAmenities = {
       "status": "success",
       "count": 3,
       "data": [{
        "amenityId": "1",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Lift",
       
      },
      {
       
        "amenityId": "2",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Gym",
      },
      {
       
        "amenityId": "3",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
      },
      {
       
        "amenityId": "4",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Power backup",
      },
      {
       
        "amenityId": "5",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Security",
      },

       ]
     };



        var particularPropertyAmenity = [   {
        "amenityName": "Lift",
        "amenityStatus": "Active"
      },
      {
       "amenityName": "Security",
        "amenityStatus": "Active"
      }
    ]

     htmlString += '<form>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br></br><span id="linz"></span>';
    
     $.each( allAmenities['data'], function( key, value ) {
      
     htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="'+value.amenityName+'"> '+value.amenityName+''; 
     });
     $('#linz').append(htmlString); 

    htmlString +='</form>';

   $('.rentEdit').empty().append(htmlString); 
           $.each( particularPropertyAmenity, function( key, value ) {  
               if(value.amenityStatus=="Active")
               {
                $("input[value='"+value.amenityName+"']").prop("checked",true);
               }
                 
               });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentEdit"></div>
```

Comment: Think like both array values has to come dynamic.that how it will work this code

Comment: Note that since jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method should be used to set "checked" instead of the .attr() method:

`$( "input" ).prop( "checked", true );`

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'checked' to your amenity data and use it to set specific boxes to be checked.

```
var htmlString = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allAmenities = {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
        "amenityId": "1",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Lift",
      }, {
        "amenityId": "2",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Gym",
      }, {
        "amenityId": "3",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
      }, {

        "amenityId": "4",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Power backup",
      }, {
        "amenityId": "5",
        "propertylistId": "1",
        "amenityName": "Security",
      },

    ]
  };
  var particularPropertyAmenity = [{
    "amenityName": "Lift",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }, {
    "amenityName": "Security",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }]

  htmlString += '<form>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br></br><span id="linz"></span>';

  $.each(allAmenities['data'], function(key, value) {
    var active = false;
    $.each(particularPropertyAmenity, function(i, v) {
      if (v.amenityName == value.amenityName) {
        active = v.amenityStatus == "Active";
        return;
      }
    });
    htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="' + value.amenityName + '" ' + (active ? 'checked' : '') + '> ' + value.amenityName + '';
  });
  $('#linz').append(htmlString);

  htmlString += '</form>';

  $('.rentEdit').empty().append(htmlString);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpwkyw37/1/

Comment: FYI you can use snippet in your answer toolbar instead of making a fiddle.

Comment: Think like both array values has to come dynamic.that how it will work this code

Comment: I have updated my answer to use the particularPropertyAmenity variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your script.

```
$.each(particularPropertyAmenity, function(key, value) {
  $("input[value='"+value.amenityName+"']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```js
var htmlString = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
  var allAmenities = {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [{
      "amenityId": "1",
      "propertylistId": "1",
      "amenityName": "Lift",    
    }, {   
      "amenityId": "2",
      "propertylistId": "1",
      "amenityName": "Gym",
    }, {     
      "amenityId": "3",
      "propertylistId": "1",
      "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
    }, {       
      "amenityId": "4",
      "propertylistId": "1",
      "amenityName": "Power backup",
    }, {
      "amenityId": "5",
      "propertylistId": "1",
      "amenityName": "Security",
    }]
  };

  var particularPropertyAmenity = [   {
    "amenityName": "Lift",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }, {
    "amenityName": "Security",
    "amenityStatus": "Active"
  }]

  htmlString += '<form>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br></br><span id="linz"></span>';
    
  $.each( allAmenities['data'], function( key, value ) {
    htmlString += 'Amenities:  <input type="checkbox" name="amenity_check[]"  class="customcheckbox" value="'+value.amenityName+'"> '+value.amenityName+''; 
  });
  $('#linz').append(htmlString); 

  htmlString +='</form>';

  $('.rentEdit').empty().append(htmlString); 
  
  $.each(particularPropertyAmenity, function(key, value) {
    $("input[value='"+value.amenityName+"']").prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentEdit"></div>
```

Comment: Don't give static , i need particularPropertyAmenity  array what are the amenityName are there, i want to make that value is checked, but here you are giving static $("input[value='Lift']").prop('checked', true);
            $("input[value='Security']").prop('checked', true);

Comment: Think like both array values has to come dynamic.that how it will work this code